# Set the value of all inputs that are children of a jquery object assigned to a variable

Tags: jquery

I have a function to which I pass a jquery object

```
function throwBox(div){
    if(typeof div !== 'undefined'){
        div.children(":text").val('');
    }
    div.css({'left':'-10000px'});
}
```

which I would call like so

```
throwBox($("#myDiv"));
```

I can't seem to find the right combination to make the function clear the text inputs which are children of my argument object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the inputs are in fact children of the div, and not simply descendants?

```
function throwBox(div){
    if(typeof div !== 'undefined'){
        div.find(":text").val('');
    }
    div.css({'left':'-10000px'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
div.find(":text").val('');
```

`jQuery.children` only grabs the immediate children, while `jQuery.find` will search all descendents. You could also jsut use `div` as the context like:

```
$(':text', div);
```